# How to Scale up an Application Service from PremiumV2 to PremiumV3 when it's not available

Tags: azure, migration, azure-web-app-service

We are planning to scale our Azure App Service to PremiumV3 to decrease our costs, however there is a limitation of Azure and so the documentation guides to create a new app service and then redeploy the application. But we really need to perform a complete migration for the following:

1. We have more than 170 domains pointed to this Application Service
2. We need to keep our public IP, otherwise we will lose the pointers from our customers.

We have tried:

1. Create new V3 plan, in the same region and in the same Resource Group but the console informs that this is not possible.
2. Cloning the app from the console, but nothing happens.

Does anyone have any suggestions on this situation?

Thanks